# Alignment of elements ruined when value entered into one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid, which when you click on a cell, you can enter a value. However my attempts to then enter this value into the grid cause the whole grid to misalign.
https://jsfiddle.net/retsek860/963kqzmj/

As well as adding the value entered into the html it changes the font-size of that cell. Because previously the font-size was zero. However this changing of the font size causes the box to no longer fit in with all the others.

```
function createGrid() {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
            cell = "<div class='grid' "
            if (rows%3==2) {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (rows%3==0) {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==2) {
                cell += "1px 0 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==0) {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 #000;'></div>"
            } else {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150);'></div>"
            }
            $("#container").append(cell);
        }
    }
    $(".grid").width(90);
    $(".grid").height(90);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    createGrid()

    $(".grid").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "lightgrey")
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "none")
        }
    );

    $(".grid").click(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "") {
            var input = prompt("Input a number");
            $(this).html(input);
            $(this).css("fontSize", 20);
        }
    });

});
```

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    outline:2px solid #000;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin:auto;
    height:810px;
    width:810px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.grid {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Add `display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap;` to your `#container` CSS and you'll be up and running again...

Answer (score 0):

Try entering something to be placeholder until user enters something (e.g empty space, maybe white colored character/s)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left` to the mix, so that the misalignment stops and use some flexbox properties to center the numbers:

```css
.grid {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    /* Try adding these to the mix: */
    float: left;
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fngrk6y/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the below code changes:

```js
#container {
   display: flex; 
   flex-flow: row wrap;
...
}

.grid {
...
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Please, refer the full code below:

```js
function createGrid() {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < 9; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < 9; columns++) {
            cell = "<div class='grid' "
            if (rows%3==2) {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "style='box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (rows%3==0) {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "0 -1px 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==2) {
                cell += "1px 0 0 #000, "
            } else {
                cell += "1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150), "
            }
            if (columns%3==0) {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 #000;'></div>"
            } else {
                cell += "-1px 0 0 rgb(150, 150, 150);'></div>"
            }
            $("#container").append(cell);
        }
    }
    $(".grid").width(90);
    $(".grid").height(90);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    createGrid()

    $(".grid").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "lightgrey")
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css("background", "none")
        }
    );

    $(".grid").click(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "") {
            var input = prompt("Input a number");
            $(this).html(input);
            $(this).css("fontSize", 20);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
display: flex; 
   flex-flow: row wrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
 outline:2px solid #000;
 font-size: 0px;
 margin:auto;
 height:810px;
 width:810px;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}

.grid {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
    border:none;
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sudoku Solver</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="sudokuSolver.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <button class='solveSudoku' style="margin-right: 30px">Solve!</button><button class='clearSudoku'>Clear</button>

        <div id='container'></div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```